# How to get secret key in process of connecting flask app to database

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I m following a tutorial on making a database connection between Flask and PostgreSQL using json, and there is a secret key, mentioned in config.py

I have read some other answers and understood Flask uses urandom to generate a random key. But not exactly clear at which moment of time i must run this code to generate the secret key. I do understand that this code must be run on command prompt.

```
python
    >>> import os
    >>> os.urandom(24)
```

My config.py code

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'this-really-needs-to-be-changed'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['postgresql://postgresql:silverTip@localhost/DatabaseFirst']

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False

class StagingConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True

class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Run that code in a python shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(24)
b'\x1d\xc6\x0f[\xed\x18\xd6:5\xe0\x0f\rG\xaf\xb4\xf4HT\xef\xc1\xf1\xa89f'
```

Then copy/paste the result into your config file:

```
SECRET_KEY = '\x1d\xc6\x0f[\xed\x18\xd6:5\xe0\x0f\rG\xaf\xb4\xf4HT\xef\xc1\xf1\xa89f'
```

Remember to remove the leading `b`, otherwise you will saving the `SECRET_KEY` as a bytes object, rather than a string.